# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is not working in Android 4.1

Tags: android, filepath, android-sdcard

This is a bit weird, I'm unable to get full path of a file on my sdcard. The console shows that no file or directory is found. Here is what I've been trying so far:

```
File file1=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/CDAInfo.txt");
    fileArray.add(file1);
```

Logcat:

```
 03-22 15:54:10.459: E/AndroidRuntime(17542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 15:54:10.459: E/AndroidRuntime(17542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vinit.airdrive/com.vinit.airdrive.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 15:54:10.459: E/AndroidRuntime(17542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)
03-22 15:54:10.459: E/AndroidRuntime(17542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088
```

Any help please?

Comment: did you define permision to read eXternal storage

Comment: yes, It's been defined already..

Comment: i want to know CDAInfo.txt file is on sd card or not?

Comment: Of course it is there. I'm emulating the code on real device.

Comment: please check your device is having external storage, some of the device is having only internal storage. plz verify and then check your code on real device.

Comment: I've Sony Xperia and yes, it does have only internal storage. But even the hard coded path string is not working.. like /sdcard/CDAInfo.txt... This is getting extremely frustrating! :(

Comment: see the solution of your problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718564/how-to-create-a-folder-in-internal-storage-like-whatsapp-or-allo/40718616?noredirect=1#comment68665077_40718616)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    File file1= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),"CDAInfo.txt");
```

Comment: Already tried this... the app force closes with file not found exception.. I don't really understand, the same program was working fine last day. I've checked my manifest file many times. Even deleted and re-created read permission, but of no use!

Comment: If this happening in emulator then edit emulator properties and give some size of sdcard and then check.

Answer (score 1):

i found problem, your phone does not have external storage so do like this

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
//External storage available
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
//only internal available
        } else {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
// no one is available
        }
```

please read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

please get path like this,

```
  File file1=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/CDAInfo.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort... but I've already tried this. It's not working either.

Comment: try to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() instead of this.