# How to create a folder in internal storage like WhatsApp or Allo?

Tags: android

I have a task to save the bitmap in internal storage. I tried in all ways. I can't get the required output. The folder created and saved in internal device in folder 
**data/user/0/data/~~**.
--tried

```
File mediaFile = new File(c.getExternalCacheDir(), "/MaherSaad");
```

worked and create folder in cache -- android/data/com.myapp.~/cache

i want to create folder and appear like that

**internal storage / Myapp / newFolder**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally found the solution 
creating a folder outside data folder

simply

```
File mFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder_Name");
            if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                boolean b =  mFolder.mkdirs();

            }
```

the mistake is not handling the **Run time permission** 
code simply ...

```
String TAG = "Permsission : ";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
```

handle permission

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        String TAG = "Permsission : ";
        if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
            //Define the path you want
            File mFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder_Name");
            if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                boolean b =  mFolder.mkdirs();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not creating a separate folder like whatsapp...

Answer (score 0):

try this function, it saves a txt file CREATING a NEW FOLDER in your internal storage (if it doesn't still exists). Don't forget to give all the permission into the Manifest file

```
public void saveData(String data){
    File root_text = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try{ File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TESTEXAMPLE");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        BufferedWriter fwv = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/sdcard/TESTEXAMPLE/SavedData.txt"), false));
        if (root_text.canWrite()) {
            fwv.write(data);
            fwv.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("MODEL", "ERRORE: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: ERRORE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/TESTEXAMPLE/SavedData.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

--My device not have an SD Card .. this affect ?

Comment: very strange. in fact, with this code I save within internal storage and not sdcard. Have you sat the permission in the Manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: yes 
Tried to use **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**  before not worked for me

Comment: try to comment the code from BufferedWriter until the catch and see if it creates the folder (without saving anything into it). I would like to know if the problem is the creation of the folder, or the creation of a new txt file inside the folder.

Comment: tried before using **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** many times not creating any file

Answer (score 0):

### Use the below code it is working fine.

---

```
        OutputStream os;

       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){

           ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
           ContentValues values    = new ContentValues();
           values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME,name+".jpg");
           values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpg");
           values.put(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separator+"satheesh"+File.separator+"facebook");

           Uri imgUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
           os = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imgUri));
```