# How to create a folder in internal storage like whatsapp without using getExternalStorageDirectory()?

Tags: android

Is there alternative to getExternalStorageDirectory() since it is deprecated in Android Level Q? Please provide an example using that.

Edit 1: I have used following code to save my camera stream to storage

```
            Image image = null;
            image  = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "file_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + extension);
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, values);

            try {
                uri = save(bytes,uri);
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, false);
                getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        if(image!=null)
                        {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
```

But this does not save image to storage on pressing camera button one time, On pressing capture button fastly for two times it saves it to storage. Are there any errors here?

Comment: You can do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61007602/8956604). And you can download file.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I have used your techniques but I am facing some errors. See Edit 1 in the question and please answer that.

Comment: Can you check camera code. Why it doesn't work in the first time, what happens in the second time.

Comment: Is there any mistake here like adding uri or updating it or some stuff related to Mediastore that is missing here?

Comment: Oh the mistake was in camera app only. Thanks for helping @KasımÖzdemir your solution worked

Comment: I thought so, too. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Check android sdk version. And please use [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os. Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
   // only for up to android Q
   // Use getExternalFilesDir()
   ...
} else { 
   // Use getExternalStorageDirectory()
   ...
}
```

Comment: But getExternalFilesDir() create folder like Internal_Storage->Android->data->com.example.appname->files. I want to create something like Internal_Storage->App_Name->Pictures or sounds or videos

Comment: @Coder have you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/40727170/7575602

Comment: Yup. But it uses getExternalStorageDirectory() thereby causing error in my phone since it has android 10